# Работа с папками в Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, dropdown

столкнулся с такой задачей, что в Unity требуется в элемент интерфейса Dropdown передавать строки с названием папок в заданной папке, и при выбранной в Dropdown папке, нажимая на кнопку, получать файлы из этой папки. Кто-то занимался подобным, возможно ли это вообще? Раньше реализовывал такое через NET, может в Unity есть что-то подобное, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно написать [Custom Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) для вашего `MonoBehaviour` скрипта. Подобный `Dropdown` делается через [EnumPopup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup.html).

Получиение файлов средствами `C#` через `System.IO`

```
import System.IO;
...
var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
for (file in fileInfo)
    print (file);
```

Дериктория `Assets` в `Unity3d` можно получить с помощью [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html).

Comment: А получить список string с названием папок в этой папке у меня так получится?